# What is the simple free ssh software?

Tags: ssh, terminal

What is the simple free ssh software?

Comment: Information overload!

Comment: What OS?  Are you asking about server-side or client-side?

Comment: Ssh. Openssh. PuTTY. Cygwin...kind of depends on your available OS. Linux LiveCD's usually have SSH on them...what OS are you talking about?

Answer (score 15):

For windows there's [PuTTy](http://www.putty.org/)

for any *ix OS try typing: `ssh`

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH, is the ssh that is sent with all linux dists and the bsd-unix:es.

It is quite wasy to use.

Comment: Methinks OP is asking about Windows, seeing as everything else almost always comes pre-installed with the ssh command. And on Windows, PuTTY is based on this, and that was already mentioned, so meh.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac and Linux start a terminal and run "ssh user@host" but I guess you'd have figured that out already if you were using one of those.

On Windows, Putty is commonly known as *the* ssh client although I personally prefer poderosa [1].

[1] http://en.poderosa.org